# Check if the variable is true to set false, have any impact?

Tags: any, generalization

Is a difference / impact to code if i set "variable = false" in an event without to check it if is true ?

Like:

```
function OnClick() { variable = true; or variable = object }
function OnMouseMove() { variable = false; or variable = null }
```

But is set every time false or null. Need to check first ?

Comment: Sure, it'll now be defined and set to `false` instead of being an undefined variable.

Comment: Thanks for a small think but important.